# Sample program for android Restful paring using xml API

Tags: android, xml, rest

I am New to Android Web Service I got clear view in Soap Parsing, Sax Parsing, Xml Parsing and Json Parsing. Now I got to move in Restful in that I verified some more web site one of that is http://ramsandroid4all.blogspot.in/2013/12/restjson-web-service-example-in-android.html
In this, restful parisng is done with Json API. I got struck in doing the restful parsing with xml API. 
If anyone having the concept of doing restful in xml API means please send me a link or sample code.
Looking forward to hearing from you